# Texture not showing correctly on specific faces

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-painting, texture-coordinates

[image: Front]

The front of the box the texture dont work on all sides, but the lid has the right texture.

[Blenderfile and texture here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ra1OuANSF-mFZE2V3GmvUmMu07xrSjP3?usp=sharing)

Best regards

Melvin

Comment: Do not add Solved into title please. This does not mark anything as solved. Accept answer if it solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to play with a coordinate "Mapping" node. First of all Apply your rotation and scale (select the box then Ctrl A, it's always a good habit, it helps to avoid unexpected behaviours). Then add a Mapping node.

If you want finer control you'll have to generate an UV map and use UV coordinates.

[image]

Comment: but, when I scale up the object the dimensions changed. what should I do?

Comment: Select the object and use Ctrl A (Apply scale). This will not affect the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Set your texture coordinate to UV instead of generated